# STRIPE checkout SESSION unknown parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, checkout

I am trying to pass some parameters in a checkout session of stripe with this code:

```
@session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  shipping: {
    adress: {
       city: 'Paris',
       country: 'France',
       line1: 'hello',
       line2: 'hello again',
       postal_code: '0000',
       state: 'whatever'
      },
    name: 'yeahman'
  },

  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA', 'FR', 'PT', 'ES']
  },
  customer_email: current_user.email,

  line_items: line_items_order,

  success_url: new_order_message_url(@order),
  cancel_url: order_url(@order)
)
```

All the attributes are listed in the stripe API doc, but I get this error:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Received unknown parameter: shipping)
```

Has anyone an idea about the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pre-fill the shipping address in Stripe Checkout. You simply provide a list of allowed countries to the `shipping_address_collection` parameter and Stripe will display input fields for your customer's to enter their shipping details into. Note that `shipping` isn't listed as a possible parameter when creating a Checkout Session:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby

Comment: Thanks @ttmarek. I need the shipping details before the checkout session to calculate the shipping fees. How can I do that without making the user enter twice the same information?

Comment: @cecileRx Ah in that case, you would need to omit the `shipping_address_collection` hash when creating the session.